# Combine rows with the same value in a particular column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a query but StoryNumber is coming back as multiple rows.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT 
    STY.[Number] StoryNumber
    ,ISNULL(SUM(DTH.[Hours]), 0) AS WorkHours
    ,MAX(CASE 
            WHEN DTH.Hours != 0
                THEN DTH.ActivityDate
            END) AS LatestActivityDate
FROM Task TSK
LEFT JOIN DailyTaskHours DTH ON TSK.PK_Task = DTH.TaskId
LEFT JOIN Story STY ON TSK.StoryId = STY.PK_Story
LEFT JOIN Sprint SPT ON STY.SprintId = SPT.PK_Sprint
LEFT JOIN Product PDT ON STY.ProductId = PDT.PK_Product
GROUP BY LEN(STY.[Number])
    ,STY.[Number]
    ,TSK.[Name]
```

This query is actually simplified and all of the JOIN conditions are required.

This is the output of the above query:

[image]

How can I combine like StoryNumber's and when there are multiple such as OHC-1 sum workhours and find the highest activitydate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove extraneous fields from your `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT STY.[Number] StoryNumber
      ,ISNULL(SUM(DTH.[Hours]), 0) AS WorkHours
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN DTH.Hours != 0
                THEN DTH.ActivityDate
           END) AS LatestActivityDate
FROM Task TSK
LEFT JOIN DailyTaskHours DTH ON TSK.PK_Task = DTH.TaskId
LEFT JOIN Story STY ON TSK.StoryId = STY.PK_Story
LEFT JOIN Sprint SPT ON STY.SprintId = SPT.PK_Sprint
LEFT JOIN Product PDT ON STY.ProductId = PDT.PK_Product
LEFT JOIN [User] USR ON TSK.PointPerson = USR.DisplayName
GROUP BY STY.[Number]
```